# How to translate a portion of page in to other language using google transalate

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-translate

I am working in Asp.net with C# and having below requirements from client. I have already done some R&D however not find any specific example in working mode from internet.

I would like to translate a portion on my webpage to a different language?

How can I do so? Note I do not want to translate a whole page.

Please see attached screenshot.
Moreover, when specific record in black rectangle will clicked, it will open third party website link in my website popup in IFRAME. I want to translate that page to particular! language, can I do so?

Please see image for more detail.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using WebRequest Class In Asp.Net
receive Response From Web URL
and Read Resoponse In Your Page
http://translate.google.com/#en/mr/My%20Name%20Is%20ganesh

URL/#FromLanguage/ToLanguage/Text You Want To Translate

```
string url="save Above URL HERE";
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
    Stream s = response.GetResponseStream();
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s))
    {
        s.Flush();
        resultString = sr.ReadToEnd();


    }
```